# Cannot delete last commit on REMOTE

Tags: git

Before anything, I'd like to stress that I'm the only one working on the repository.

So basically, I made a commit `eb066742` on local branch `devel` and pushed it to `origin/devel`. Then I remembered I had left something out of the commit, so I made a few changes, then `git add -u` and `git commit --amend`.

Now everything is messed up. I'm unable to `git push`

```
 ! [rejected]        devel -> devel (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'abcd.com'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

`git push -f`

```
Counting objects: 13, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 836 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 7 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected.
remote: Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the 'Note
remote: about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
To abcd
 ! [remote rejected] devel -> devel (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'abcd'
```

If I try to remove the last commit on origin/devel with `git push remote +HEAD^:devel`, I get similar error as above.

What can I do?

I just want to remove the last commit on `origin` and the push my current (amended) commit.

Answer (score 1):

I used a dirty hack. Removed the branch on origin, then re-added it. Not sure if this is the best solution, but well it worked.

Answer (score 1):

> [remote rejected] devel -> devel (pre-receive hook declined)

There is a pre-receive hook on the remote that rejects non-fast-forward updates, even if you use -f (or --force). You need to disable the hook in order to push the amended commit.

Hooks reside in folder `.git/hooks`, and to disable it, you need to rename it or move it out from the folder completely. You can learn more about git hooks here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--force` to force a change... 
but be wary of it, it's very dangerous.

Make sure it's what you really want to do. Then double-check.

and don't ever get in the habit of using `--force` ... if you have to use it a lot... then it's a good indicator that something else is wrong and should be fixed (probably your process).